# Storing multiple results from stored procedures in a field in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
  CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SampleProc`()
   BEGIN
           DECLARE X  INT;

           SET X = 1;
           WHILE X  <= 1890 DO
           SET @paperid=(SELECT PaperID FROM scrpd_paper_authors WHERE AuthorID=X);     
       SELECT AuthorID FROM scrpd_paper_authors WHERE PaperID=@paperid
       SET  X = X + 1;
          END WHILE;
   END$$

 DELIMITER ;

mytable                                           scrpd_paper_authrs                            

 ID     co_authors                             PaperID      AuthorId      
 ====   =========                             =========     ========
 1                                                1             1
 2                                                2             2
 3                                                3             3
 4                                                3             4
 5                                                3             5

                         mytable(expected result)

                          ID            co_authors
                         =====          ==========
                           1                 0
                           2                 0
                           3                 4,5
                           4                 3,5
                           5                 3,4
```

So, now the AuthorID is holding multiple rows. I want to insert these rows in a table using the where clause but I get this error:

> "subquery returns more than one row"

For example, if I get the results 1,2,3 on using the select, I want them to be stored in mytable (co_authors) as 1,2,3 where ID=1. co_authors is the column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR select ...
```

and then iterate `cur` and insert data

instead of

```
SET @paperid=(SELECT ...
```

Comment: I've never used a cursor could you please tell me how this exactly works and syntax

Comment: can the cursor be declared in a while loop because as shown in the code I need the value of x to change on every iteration

Answer (score 0):

I guess this query that caused the error :

```
SET @paperid=(SELECT PaperID FROM scrpd_paper_authors WHERE AuthorID=X);
```

Try to change your query like this :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SampleProc`()
BEGIN
      DECLARE X  INT;

      SET X = 1;
      WHILE X  <= 1890 DO
          INSERT INTO mytable(co_authors)
          SELECT AuthorID FROM scrpd_paper_authors WHERE PaperID in (SELECT PaperID FROM scrpd_paper_authors WHERE AuthorID=X)
          SET  X = X + 1;
      END WHILE;
END$$
```

Comment: Since mytable already exists I think I have to use update and when I use update I get the same error

Comment: what do you mean with "already exists"? my query don't have update syntax

Comment: Its a table having multiple fields. The ID field is already filled and now after processing the data I want to fill its co_author field. When I use insert it starts to insert right after the previous record

Comment: okey, you want to fill co_author field..fill by what? can you post your table structure in your question?

Comment: I have added the table structure in my question

Comment: on more, please post the output that you expected based on your table data

Comment: the expected result has been posted